# How to store a lot of different timetables in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, timetable

I need help about how to model a database. I need to store the timetable for each transport public line. Lets see what we have...

- I have different lines (bus number 100, 101, 102 and so on).
- Each line has different stops and I need to store the coordinates of each one of them.
- Each stop has a specific timetable, for example:
  http://rozklady.mpk.krakow.pl/aktualne/0106/0106t001.htm
  http://rozklady.mpk.krakow.pl/aktualne/0106/0106t003.htm

The aim of the program that I'm developing is to check for errors in the official timetables. Each bus has a tracking GPS device that sends its position to a database every 10 seconds. So I must check the hour of the reports whose coordinates are close to the coordinates of one of the stops and compare that time with the official time, and in case there is a big difference, create a row in other table STATISTICS reporting the issue.

Anyway, this was just for the context. The truth is that I don't have any clue about how to store it in an efficient way.

I thought about creating a table with the Stops: STOP_ID (PK) - NAME - LAT - LON - LINE - TIMETABLE

Where timetable would be an array containing all the times serialized for that stop [5:03,5:25,5:50,6:12,...].

Although I think this is not a good solution, I can't think about a better approach.

Maybe I could create a table for the stops, and other for timetables, but what would be the columns for timetables? I have so many variables... if it's weekly, saturday or holiday, a lot of hours, minutes... and all different for each stop.

Could you share any thoughts about how to face this problem? Thank you very much!!

Comment: I suggest you do further research, or hire someone that can help you with this design and implementation.  I'm afraid this isn't really what this site is for.  There's no way to avoid it costing you either time and/or money.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net I'm working on my final project for university. I made an Android app, and some other stuff. I had the whole project finished and my coordinator wanted to add this feature (some simple software to check if there are some mistakes on timetables). The only way I think this is possible is making this database and some php scripts, but I don't know how to face this design in an efficient way. As you can imagine now, I'm not going to hire someone, I'm just asking for some thoughts or help in this area. I have been researching but I still have a lot of doubts. Thank you anyway...

Comment: The short answer is that you'd want to store your data in a normalised database.  Read up on database normalisation and work out what your tables will need to store, i.e. `stops` `route` `routeHasStops`, then maybe a `scheduledStop` table that would record expected stops for a given `routeHasStops` row, and then a logging table that would log the actual date/time against the `routeHasStops` pkid.  Add in lat/lng and other data as required, some data collection, processing, and hey presto you will have your data.  If you have specific troubles on this path, I'd be happy to offer help though :)

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I will read further about database normalisation, but I guess I won't apply it for this project, because it seems too big for the time we have left (1 week more or less), and my project was already quite huge. There are more than 180 lines, with an average of 50 stops per line, a schedule for each one... its crazy. Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: Ok that would be one hell of a lot of data entry.  It sounds like a nice idea, but yes perhaps beyond the scope of your resources.  Though it depends on whether you have the source data available in a format that is able to be read, in which case 1 line or 1000 it's the same solution once you have the data structure there.  Then again seeing as it's running on Android I assume resources for processing may be limited compared to a regular DB server

Comment: The idea would be to have it running on MYSQL server and access it from the device. Anyway, I think I will do a little demonstration of how it would work as Ollie Jones suggested, and I will leave the complete development as a future project (one that I would be very interested in). And yes, you're right, if you have an accessible source data format I guess is just a matter of parsing it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

As Simon mentioned, you are starting a big project.

Suggestion:  Read up on the various normal forms for relational DBMSs; this will give you some helpful background if you don't have it.

What are your entities (tables)?
Bus lines (consider the outbound trip and return trip to be two different lines).
Stations on those lines, ordered.
Trips (e.g. 106 bus leaves central station at 05:22, another trip at 05:42, etc).
Scheduled-stops
GPS observations.

Here are possible tables and columns:

```
 Busline table:   one row for each busline.   
   Busline  e.g. 106-outbound or 108-inbound   (pk)
   Description

 Station table:   one row for each bus stop, including ends of trips
   Busline        part of pk, fk to Busline  e.g. 106
   Stationid      part of pk  kf to Station 
   Description    e.g. Second Avenue Eastbound at Houston Street
   lat
   long

 Trip table: One row for each bus trip.
   Tripid   pk
   Busline  fk to Busline
   Description  e.g.   05:22 trip Central Station to University Park

 Schedule table:  one row for each scheduled time for each trip at each stop 
   Scheduleid  pk ... ascending serial number.
   Busline     fk to Station
   Stationid   fk to Station
   Tripid      fk to Trip
   Time

 Observation table  a row for each of your GPS readings
   Observationid  pk  ... ascending serial number
   Busline if you know it   fk to Busline
   Tripid if you have it    fk to Trip
   Time
   Lat
   Long
```

My advice with RDBMS design is to avoid serializing multiple items of data into single DBMS columns.  That's why I have suggested the Schedule table.

Once you figure out how to load your Busline, Station, Trip, and Schedule tables, and you've loaded your observations into the Observation table, it will be an interesting exercise to correlate your observations with your schedules.

Be careful!  You may embarrass your municipal transport department!  :-)

Comment: For a limited project like yours, you may choose to measure just a few stations on just a few buslines and trips.  You could measure the first, middle, and last stops for two trips each on the two most popular buslines.   That would demonstrate and prove the value of your tech.  At any rate, don't serialize multiple data items into single columns, unless you want a great pain in the neck! Oh, and you will need to use a proximity rather than equality criterion for your GPS coordinates.  Look up the haversine formula.

Comment: Haha, I hope not to embarras anyone XD Thank you very much for sharing your ideas and taking the time to help me. Right now, I'm really interested in developing it, I mean, in matters of learning and practicing, but I'm afraid this is too big for the time I have left, bigger than I expected at the beggining. I will ask my coordinator to leave this as a future improvement, as a continuation of the project. I really hope to be able to take the time to learn and develop it in the near future.

Comment: Sorry, I posted without reading your latest answer. I think it's a great idea to just do a little demonstration of how could it work with just a few lines and a few stops of each one of them. And to leave the complete development as a future project. And yes, I had already taken a look at haversine formula for proximity measurement in order to compare the location of the bus reports and the stored location of each stop. Thank you very much Ollie!!

Comment: Yah, completely digitizing all the schedules for a municipal bus system is an industrial-scale project (=== huge pain in the neck) beyond the scope of a student project.